# When I press the button and enter value 2, it doesn't execute else if command

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

First of all I would like to apologize, since the following code has been written in Danish and might not make any sense to non-danish people.

I've written this piece of code:

[JS Link](https://jsfiddle.net/MonkeyInMyPants/tceuo3aq/5/)

The important part with the code is this, but I am not sure if this is where the issue is:

```
function udregnAnalyseAr() {
        var virksomhedsnavn = prompt("Hvad hedder den virksomhed du arbejder med?");
        var analysear;
        var ar = parseFloat(prompt("Hvor mange analyseår er der?"));
```

and later down:

```
if (ar === 1.00) {
        var afkastningsgrad1 = parseFloat(prompt("Hvad er afkastningsgraden på i det første år? (Det mindste år)")); 
        if (afkastningsgrad1 <= 4.00)
        {
        value1 = "Afkastningsgraden i år 1 er blevet registreret til " + afkastningsgrad1 + " %. Den er på et utilfredsstillende niveau sammenlignet med markedsrenten på 3 % plus et risikotillæg (marts 2016). <br>";
        }
        else if (afkastningsgrad1 > 4.00)
        {value1 = "Afkastningsgraden i år 1 er blevet registreret til " + afkastningsgrad1 + " %. Den er på et tilfredsstillende niveau sammenlignet med markedsrenten på 3 % plus et risikotillæg (marts 2016). <br>";
        }
        else
        {value1 = "Afkastningsgraden er blevet indtastet forkert.<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("afkastningDataTxt").innerHTML = value1
        }

    else if (ar === 2) {
        var afkastningsgrad1 = parseFloat(prompt ("Hvad er afkastningsgraden på i det første år? (Det mindste år)")); 
        if (afkastningsgrad1 <= 4.00)
        {
        value1 = "Afkastningsgraden i år 1 er blevet registreret til " + afkastningsgrad1 + " %. Den er på et utilfredsstillende niveau sammenlignet med markedsrenten på 3 % plus et risikotillæg (marts 2016). <br>";
        }
        else if (afkastningsgrad1 > 4.00)
        {value1 = "Afkastningsgraden i år 1 er blevet registreret til " + afkastningsgrad1 + " %. Den er på et tilfredsstillende niveau sammenlignet med markedsrenten på 3 % plus et risikotillæg (marts 2016). <br>";
        }
        else
        {value1 = "Afkastningsgraden er blevet indtastet forkert.<br>";
        }
```

My issue is that when I define "ar" as 2 in my first function, it doesn't care about the value in my second function. It automatically acts as if ar = 1 and launches the if execution.

Comment: Proper indentation usually goes a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare "ar" as :
ar = parseFloat(prompt("Hvor mange analyseår er der?"));
instead of declaring it as :
var ar = parseFloat(prompt("Hvor mange analyseår er der?"));

The reason is you have to access the value of ar in the second function, while declaring a variable with "var" makes it local and non-accessible out side its scope. While declaring the variable with no "var" will make it global.

Another thing you can try is passing the variable in the second function when you call it. That ways, you don't have to declare the variable "ar" globally.

So it should go something like this :

In HTML :

```
<button onClick="udregnAnalyseAr()">Rentabilitet</button>
```

In JavaScript

```
function udregnAnalyseAr() {
//implementation of function
var ar =  parseFloat(prompt("Hvor mange analyseår er der?"));
afkastningData(ar);// call the other function here instead of calling it from html itself.
}
function ;afkastningData(ar){
//implementation of function
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to make such an adequate answer. I did like you suggested at first and defined it as ar = (...) instead of var ar = (...), so now it works like a charm.

Comment: Your welcome. Caution is that the first solution will pollute the global namespace which is not a good practice. Also please accept the answer if it is working, so that other can refer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using a single equal sign in your if statements. You want to be using three instead. This makes sure that the value and type are equal to each other.

For example:

```
if (ar === 1.00)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion.
However when I change it to === it completely ignores the function.
Do you have a solution to this as well?

Comment: Could you please update your fiddle so I could see what you have done?

Comment: This error is that the variable ar is defined in the first function, meaning it is a local variable and cannot be accessed outside of the function. Define ar outside of the function and then just the value of ar inside of the first function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the variable scope. `ar` exists only in your first function and therefore will always be `undefined` in the other one.

To fix it, either change the scope of the variable by defining it outside of the function (or by omitting `var`, which will surely make it a global as opposed to, say, being in a parent function), or figure out how to pass it to your second function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were right, and I did like binariedMe suggested and defined it as ar = (...) instead of var ar = (...)

Comment: You're welcome, I told you you can omit `var` as well. But why did you accept the only answer that **did not** address that issue?